# Any way to use the C# compiler object (CSharpCodeProvider) to build "inline"?

Tags: c#, .net, compiler-construction

I use the CSharpCodeProvider to build dynamic C# and it works great. Slightly faster then expression trees and certainly easier to maintain over expression trees and IL...

I've run into a case where it doesn't seem like its going to work.

ConsoleApp1.exe
  MyClass

I then use CSharpCodeProvider to generate an in memory temp DLL. Say, something basic like this:

void TestFunc(MyClass input)
{
}

This generates a compiler error because the CSharpCodeProvider doesn't have a reference to MyClass. Since MyClass lives in an EXE, adding a reference to the compiler object doesn't work. I get an error saying it can't find the metadata for ConsoleApp1.

Is there anyway to make the code live in the context of the EXE? Or is there some way to make the reference work? I know it works if I move MyClass to a DLL and then add that as a reference, but that's an unacceptable requirement for users of my class.

EDIT:

So, using pure expression trees, I generate this method:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[ConsoleApplication2.Source,ConsoleApplication2.Dest]>(ConsoleApplication2.Source $var1) {
    .New ConsoleApplication2.Dest(){
        S1 = .Call $var1.get_S1(),
        S2 = .Call $var1.get_S2(),
        I1 = .Call $var1.get_I1(),
        I2 = .Call $var1.get_I2(),
        S3 = .Call $var1.get_S3(),
        S4 = .Call $var1.get_S4(),
        S5 = .Call $var1.get_S5()
    }
}
```

compiled to a lambda, calling it 1M times takes ~285ms.

The "compiler" way, I generate this code:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    public class TestClass
    {
        public static ConsoleApplication2.Dest TestFunc(ConsoleApplication2.Source source)
        {
            ConsoleApplication2.Dest d = new ConsoleApplication2.Dest();

            d.S1 = source.S1;
            d.S2 = source.S2;
            d.I1 = source.I1;
            d.I2 = source.I2;
            d.S3 = source.S3;
            d.S4 = source.S4;
            d.S5 = source.S5;

            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I build a typed lambda off of that:

```
    ParameterExpression p1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Source));
    var v = Expression.Lambda<Func<Source, Dest>>(Expression.Call(mi, p1), new ParameterExpression[] { p1 }).Compile();
```

When I call v(obj) 1M times, it only takes 133ms 1/2 the time of the pure expression tree.

I'm just hesitant to go this route due to the requirement of the classes having to be public in the EXE or even in a DLL.

Any idea why the expression tree is so much slower?

Comment: Sounds like you have a chicken-egg problem - you are building the dynamic DLL within an executable, but the dynamic DLL needs to reference the executable to compile. If so the answer is to move `MyClass` to a class library that the console app and dynamic DLL both reference.  Or go back to using expression trees :)

Comment: Can you show us some code? Specifically what is MyClass define in/compiled into? There should be no problem having an executable as a reference assembly.

Comment: @DStanley - hmm... my bad... apparently you *can* add an EXE as a reference, but you have to specifically append .EXE to the assembly name. Also, the types have to be public in the EXE. So that resolved that part, but it doesn't add much performance.

Comment: @mikez yeah, I did get it to work... weird though... I wrapped the delegate to the method in an expression lambda and my bench was 133ms, using pure expression trees it was 288ms. Not sure why the pure expression trees takes that much longer...

Comment: You're worried about an extra 150ms for 1M calls?  Is that significant to the performance of the application overall?

Comment: @DStanley -- 150ms for 1M call is just for my POC. As I add features and bells of whistles, that will go up... I was wondering why the diff and if I can do something to the expression tree to make it work faster.

Comment: @SledgeHammer: That is normal delegate overhead. Unless you find a way to remove the delegate call, it wont get better.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Well, perhaps, but it sounds like a micro-optimization.  Use whatever tools makes _you_ most efficient, _then_ work on performance issues that are _significant_ to the application overall.  You'll spend a lot of time "optimizing" away milliseconds and potentially ignoring bigger performance bottlenecks.  Just my 2c...

Comment: @DStanley, yeah, it is "micro optimizing" at this point, I admit :)... that is kind of the point of the exercise :) trying to get this as fast as possible as a challenge / learning. It originally started out 13 SECONDS -- upon further thought though... if the types live in a DLL, they'd need to be public to be used in the app, but the compiler method still wouldn't work on types inside the DLL.

Comment: You could use reflection to get the private members :) but that would increase the time, possibly by more than you saved by using a dynamic DLL.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to make the code live in the context of the EXE?

No. The `CSharpCodeProvider` creates an assembly at *runtime*, so there's no way to "inject" that into the currently running assembly, which is a compiled assembly at that point.

> is there some way to make the reference work?

You answered this question yourself - add the EXE extension to the reference name so it knows to load an EXE rather than a DLL.